# How do you make a radio button and associated label disappear once another radio button has been checked? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, label

Im building a booking form and I'm giving the user the ability to select Dates, Times and Durations of their stay.

However, it is restricted opening times, I want the user to be able to select a time, which would in turn hide the inputs that exceed the closing time of Midnight (in this case, the value is set to 24 hours)

I'm trying to hide both elements to minimise user input error.

My code is bellow, many thanks to whoever might help.

***JS***

```
let dateRow = document.getElementById('dateCollapse');
let datePick = document.getElementById('dp1');
let showDate = document.getElementById('dateSelect');
let timeCell = document.getElementsByClassName('time-cell');
var tiSelect = document.getElementsByName('startTime');
var durSelect = document.getElementsByName('duration');
var durLabel = document.getElementsByClassName('durationLabel');


  function displayTime() {
  for(i = 0; i < tiSelect.length; i++) {
  if(tiSelect[i].checked)
    var timeDisplay = parseInt(tiSelect[i].value) % 12;
    if (timeDisplay === 0) timeDisplay = 12;
    document.getElementById("timeSelect").innerHTML = timeDisplay + " PM";
    for (x = 0; x < durSelect.length; x++) {
      var durDisplay = parseInt(durSelect[x].value);
      if (timeDisplay + durDisplay >= 24)
        
          var durId = durSelect[a].getAttribute('id');
          var durFor = durLabel.htmlFor;
          if (durId == durFor)
            durLabel.style.display = 'none';
        
        
    };
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row d-flex">
                        <div class="col mx-3 my-1 py-1 card-header bg-blk raj-wt fs-4 text-center">
                            Duration
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="row d-flex text-center mx-0">
                            <label for="1hr" for="1hr" class="col-4 mx-0 d-inline-block px-1 dur-cell durationLabel">
                                <span class="raj-wt text-center fs-6 py-1">
                                <input id="1hr" value="1" type="radio" onchange="displayEnd()" name="duration" ></input>
                                    1HR
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <label for="2hrs" class="col-4 d-inline-block mx-0 px-1 dur-cell durationLabel">
                                <span class="raj-wt text-center fs-6 py-1">
                                <input id="2hrs" value="2" type="radio" onchange="displayEnd()" name="duration" ></input>
                                    2HRS
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <label for="3hrs" class="col-4 d-inline-block mx-0 px-1 dur-cell durationLabel">
                                <span class="raj-wt text-center fs-6 py-1">
                                <input id="3hrs" value="3" type="radio" onchange="displayEnd()" name="duration" ></input>
                                    3HRS
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

The HTML code snippet I've given you, highlights a row (1 of 4) but the principals of what am I'm trying to achieve still apply.

Many thanks.

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to get that checkbox on submission you can remove it from form with remove() method in javascript.